# Is there a way to send websocket message from regular method in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket

I am building web application. There are admin and user roles provided. When user making some action admin is recieving a message that something happened. Websocket connection establishing when user logged. Is there a way to not create ws connection for user and use only HHTP protocol to sending message and send WS message from controller method only?

Now i have theese settings:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class NotificationController {
    @MessageMapping("/notification")
    @SendTo("/topic/test")
    public Notification getNotification(Notification notification) {
        return notification;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You have to inject `SimpMessagingTemplate`, with `@Autowired` or with constructor.

```
private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
public ConstructorName(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate){
    this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
}
```

In your controller, or function where you want to send the message to the client use the `convertAndSendToUser` function.

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("userId","/private", messageData);
```

On javascript client side.

```
var Sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws');
stompClient = over(Sock);
stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);

stompClient.subscribe('/topic/' + userId + '/private', onMessageReceived);
```

Comment: I had to change '/topic/' in subscribe on client side to '/user/' and it works!